# How can to check for first pattern on the line with awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a confusing (*to me*) example here.  This `awk` expression gives the desired result and prints: "`match`"

```
$ echo -e "<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n<databaseChangeLog" |
  awk  -e'/[[:space:]]*<?xml /{ print "match"; } { quit 0; }'
match
$
```

We actually want things so that any match is the first pattern on the line.  This should be the beginning of string/line anchor,`^` as far as I know.  And yet adding `^` fails as shown:

```
$ echo -e "<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n<databaseChangeLog" |
  awk  -e'/^[[:space:]]*<?xml /{ print "match"; } { quit 0; }'
$ 
$ # NO match
```

Using `gawk`, version:

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.
  ...
```

What's missing?

Comment: First thing first you need not to have `-e` option before running `awk` program. Then I have tested both of your `awk` programs(with and without `-e` option) and I am getting match in both of programs output. I am using gawk with 5.0.1 version, which awk version you are using, though I don't think awk version could be an issue but asking in case I have it, could try to replicate it once, cheers.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Add `^` to your regular expression, not to the input string. To match 0 or more spaces followed by `<?xml ` at the beginning of a line use: `^\s*<\?xml ` (`\s` is a shorthand for `[[:space:]]`). Do not forget the backslash before the question mark. Else it matches 0 or 1 times the preceding character: `<?xml` matches `<xml` or `xml` but not `<?xml`.

Comment: @Cyrus I do agree that regex is wrong tool for parsing XML, but if intention is only detection (i.e. does it looks like XML file?) then regex might be enough for that

Comment: @RenaudPacalet ... Thank you, yes a confusing typo.  Sorry folk.

Comment: @Cyrus ... Yes, not parsing XML, just want to know why this example fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the `^` to your input instead of adding it to the regexp in your code that's supposed to match the input, i.e. you did:

```
$ echo '^foobar' | awk '/bar/'
^foobar
```

Instead of:

```
$ echo 'foobar' | awk '/^bar/'
$
```

You're also using a `?` regexp metachar but want a literal `?` instead and you're trying to use a non-existent keyword `quit` when I assume you mean `exit` (so what your code actually does is concatenate an undefined variable with the number `0` resulting in the string `0` which you then just discard) but you only exit with `0` which is the default anyway so that's all redundant.

I think this might be what you're trying to do:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]*<\?xml /{ f=1; exit } END{ if (f) print "match"; exit !f }'
```

e.g.:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' '<databaseChangeLog' |
    awk '/^[[:space:]]*<\?xml /{ f=1; exit } END{ if (f) print "match"; exit !f }'
match
$ echo $?
0
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' '<databaseChangeLog' |
    awk '/^[[:space:]]*<\?xml /{ f=1; exit } END{ if (f) print "match"; exit !f }'
$ echo $?
1
```

The above will work in any POSIX awk. If you have a very old awk that doesn't support POSIX character classes then just change `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t]` and that will work in any awk.

Consider also printing match or no match to stderr:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' '<databaseChangeLog' |
    awk '/^[[:space:]]*<\?xml /{ f=1; exit } END{ print (f ? "" : "no ") "match" | "cat>&2"; exit !f }'
match

$ printf '%s\n' 'foo<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' '<databaseChangeLog' |
    awk '/^[[:space:]]*<\?xml /{ f=1; exit } END{ print (f ? "" : "no ") "match" | "cat>&2"; exit !f }'
no match
```

Comment: Unfortunately the garet(`^`) was misplaced in the command.  I ought remove the question.  It is probably a bit confusing now.